# Sesame RDF store/query on Android

Tags: android, rdf

I want to do an Android application that use RDF store in-memory and query it. Do you know if you can use Sesame 2.3.2 onejar library in Android application without problem?

Thanks!

Comment: No idea personally but try asking on www.semanticoverflow.com as well as I know a few of the authors of Sesame check the site occassionally

Answer (score 1):

1. should rewrite info.aduna.lang.service.ServiceRegistry, using java.util.ServiceLoader instead of javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry to load service.
2. when build apk, should include files in META-INF/services of openrdf-sesame-2.3.2-onejar.jar. Just using 'jar uc' to insert them into apk, then re-sign the apk file.

Comment: Thank you very much. I finally used Jena, because with Androjena is easier to do.